# grails searcheable plugin search in inner hasMany class

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-searchable

Hello I am reading the standard documentation for grails searcheable plugin at http://grails.org/Searchable+Plugin+-+Mapping+-+Class+Property+Mapping It describes searcheable references and components in that.

In the classic scenario discussed on the page if I have

```
class News {
    static searchable = true
    static hasMany = [comments: Comment]
    String text
}
```

and

```
class Comment {
    static searchable = true
    String text
}
```

If I am searching by `News.search("a phrase", params)` what do I have to change in this query so that "a phrase" is searched into news as well as comments of news?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to configure `comments` as `component`:

```
class News {
  static searchable = true
  static hasMany = [comments: Comment]
  String text
  static searchable = {
    comments component: [prefix:'comment']
  }
}
```

This allows you to search for a specific comments through `News.search("componenttext:phrase", params)`, but afaik, `News.search("a phrase", params)` will also search through the comments.

btw: have you already discovered luke? http://code.google.com/p/luke/ This tool will help you a lot while working with the lucene index. For instance, it shows you how lucene sees you grails domain class.